# How to create a variable for when other variable takes up highest value, with conditions on countries?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, stata

I'm trying to create a new variable under conditions on other variables. I have countries in Africa with each country divided into constituencies;  for each I have the number of votes for a candidate.

I am trying to work for one country at a time (`country=ctr`) and to create the value in each constituency (`cst`)

I would like to create a variable `win1 = 2` when the votes take the highest value in a given constituency, and in a given country.

I have tried :

```
by cst : replace win1=2 if cv1=max(cv1) in (ctr==566)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
by ctr cst (cv1) : replace win1=2 if cv1==cv1[_N]
```

Errors:

`in` is for observation numbers. It's not an alternative to `if`.

You need `==` to test equality, not `=`.

`max()` as a Stata function requires two or more arguments and works rowwise, not across groups of observations.

This code assumes no missing values.

It's also easier than you think in so far as you can work with several countries at once.